What's the difference between a React.FunctionComponent and just a function?
Using TypeScript I usually define my own components using syntax like this:
// define an Options element and a viewOptions property

type OptionsProps = {
  viewOptions: ViewOptions;
};
export const Options: React.FunctionComponent<OptionsProps> = (props: OptionsProps) => {
  const {viewOptions} = props;
  // CODE here to render elements using viewOptions
}

My question, could I systematically use this instead?
// do the same as a simple arrow function

export const Options = (viewOptions: ViewOptions): JSX.Element => {
  // CODE here to render elements using viewOptions
}

I guess the only difference is in how they're invoked:

<Options viewOptions={viewOptions}/> -- an element
{Options(viewOptions)} -- a function call

Is there any other difference

In usability? Even the latter syntax seems to be a "React Function", from the top of which I can invoke (use) a hook.
Or in behaviour -- e.g. in whether something is re-rendered if the argument changes?


Does this answer your question? React Functional component: calling as function vs. as component

Technically that's a different question (i.e. what happens if it's declared a FunctionComponent and called as a function). Its top-voted answer says, "If you call functional component directly, you are calling a custom hook actually." I don't know but I guess that doesn't happen if it's not even declared as a FunctionComponent, like what I'm asking, so ... but maybe by studying those answers I'll understand more.

It doesn't matter whether or not it's "declared as a FunctionComponent", TypeScript does not exist at runtime and it's still just a function (in fact even when you are using it as a component that type's generally discouraged, see e.g. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177).

Check again but you can "invoke" a component with both way you mentioned as React.FunctionComponent is returning a ReactElement. Using the React.FunctionComponent generic (you can also use React.FC) would be recommended as it also contains additional declaration like propTypes, displayName, etc...

TypeScript's not existing at run-time would imply they're identical. Perhaps I'm not sure what the TSX compiler does, whether that adds magic -- for example "the state mounts in the parent fibre" or I don't know what.

The obvious difference in that example is that you have different parameter types, props is not the same type as viewOptions. The more direct equivalent would be:
export const Options = ({viewOptions}: OptionsProps): JSX.Element => {
  // CODE here to render elements using viewOptions
}

And this is the same function, but without some of the explicit typing. You can remove even more:
export const Options = ({viewOptions}: OptionsProps) => {
  // CODE here to render elements using viewOptions
}

Those two versions are instances of React.FunctionComponent<OptionsProps>, they are just not explicit about it.

Yes that's plausible, thank you.
